# Translating C programming into pseudocode

Tags: c, algorithm, pseudocode

I'm writing a pseudo-code for an algorithm. The result looks very much like C language because it's the language I'm most familiar with.

The code is as follows:

```
START
Declare int m, int n
Input value of m and n
Declare int array source[n], target[m][n]

For(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    Input value of source[i]

For(int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    For(int j =  0; j < n; j++)
        Input value of target[i][j]

Declare int maxsource, minsource, maxtarget, mintarget
For(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    If i == 0 
        Minsource = source[i]
        Maxsource = source[i]
    Else
        If minsource > source[i]
            Minsource = source[i]
        Else if maxsource < source[i]
            Maxsource = source[i]
        Endif
    Endif

For(int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    For(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        If j == 0
            Mintarget = target[i][j]
            Maxtarget = target[i][j]
        Else
            If mintarget > target[i][j]
                Mintarget = target[i][j]
            Else if maxtarget < target[i][j]
                Maxtarget = target[i][j]
            Endif
        Endif
    If minsource == mintarget && maxsource == maxtarget
        Print true
        STOP
    Else if maxtarget > maxsource
        Print false
        STOP
    Endif

Print false
STOP
```

How do I turn this into more pseudo-code-like? Any tips?

Comment: What is `pseudocode-like`? your code is alreadt in pseudocode.

Comment: Pseudo-code has different meanings dependning on the context you are working in. Here is a [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudocode) reference that could help ?

Comment: @DipStax ah, good to know. I'm just thinking maybe it's too much like a real code rather than a pseudo-code. thanks!

Comment: @sylvaan: there is one major problem in your pseudo-code: you are using small letters and capitals mixing with each other: don't do that: C++ is case sensitive, so `mintarget` and `Mintarget` are considered different.

Comment: @Dominique thanks for the advice, I was using word so the auto capitals is active

Comment: Write it in plain English first, list all the use-cases in written text. That's much more useful and an experienced programmer can take it to source code from there without some pseudo step in between.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you well, you do not want the pseudo-code to look much like a program code so that someone using different progarmming language can use it and solve the same task. I have some tips that could help you achieve that. The main idea is that you should avoid using syntactic elements of the programming language. Think in terms of the problem beign solved, not the programming language. Write your pseudo-code in simple language that any one can read and understand. It should be simple that someone with out coding skills can follow it and solve thesame task. Here is an example of simple pseudo-code of a function that finds the second maximum element in an array.

```
The function takes two inputs:
  arr - array of integers
  length - lenght of the array
It returns:
  secMax - Second maximum element
```

Then the steps (should be in a simple language)

```
Define and set the maximum and second maximum as the minimum possible value

Repeat for each element of the array
{
  If the current element is greater than the current maximu
  {
    then make current maximum as second maximum
    Make the maximum as current array element
    (Now you have new maximum and second maximum)
  }
  else if the current array element is less than maximum but is greater than second 
  maximum
  { 
  then make it second maximum
  }
 
}
return second maximum
```

As you can see I just explained the steps without using syntactic elements of any programming language. So now anyone can implement my steps using his/her comfortable language to solve the same task.

Let's say I want to implement this using C, my code will be something like this:

```
//Defining the function according to the information above
//It takes to inputs and returns an integer

int findSecondMaximum(int arr[], int length)
{
  //Define and Set the maximum and second maximum as the minimum possible value
    int max, secondMax;
    max = secondMax = INT_MIN;

  for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) //Repeat for each element of the array
  {
     //If the current element is greater than the current maximum
     if (vect[i] > max)
     {
       //then make the current maximum as second maximum
        secondMax = max;
           
      //Make the maximum as the current array element
          max = vect[i];
     }

     /*else if the current array element is less than maximum but is greater than 
     second maximum*/
     else if (vect[i] > secondMax && vect[i] < max)
     { 
       //make it second maximum
        secondMax = vect[i];
     }
 
  }
  //return second maximum
   return secondMax;
  
}
```

I hope this would help.

Answer (score 1):

Primarily check [wikipedia on pseudocode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudocode).
Either:

- use a Pascal style (for instance), or
- use a Math style

First a bug on first glance:

```
    If minsource > source[i]
        minsource = source[i]
    Else if maxsource < source[i]
        maxsource = source[i]
    Endif
```

Should be

```
    If minsource > source[i]
        minsource = source[i]
    Endif
    If maxsource < source[i]
        maxsource = source[i]
    Endif
```

The case should be consistent (minsource/Minsource).

You might introduce

```
Function {int min, int max} array_min_max(int[] array)
    min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    For value in array
        min = Math.min(min, value);
        max = Math.max(min, value);
    Endfor
Endfunction
```

Declaring at first use can be better readable.

```
Declare int minsource, maxsource
For (int i = 0; i < source.length; i++)
    If i == 0 
        minsource = source[i]
        maxsource = source[i]
    Else
        If minsource > source[i]
            minsource = source[i]
        EndIf
        If maxsource < source[i]
            maxsource = source[i]
        Endif
    Endif
Endfor

For (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    Declare int mintarget, maxtarget
    {mintarget, maxtarget} = array_min_max(target[i]);
    If minsource == mintarget && maxsource == maxtarget
        Print true
        STOP
    Else if maxtarget > maxsource
        Print false
        STOP
    Endif
Endfor

Print false
STOP
```

On the pseudo-language itself: the "Basic" above with its recognisable C I find a bit irritating. Also I would go for min_target or minTarget instead of mintarget.

There are so many languages. In Computer Science there is a long non-tradition. The high level expression language **Algol68** was used often, as it even has a **bold** type face for types and keywords. It would indeed be nice if you could use richt text.

Pascal like pseudo code, maybe borrowed from Modula with `IF THEN ELSE END`.

Personally I do not like camel case and would prefer all lower case.